# XSD: Define element with any type and any name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have following `XML` structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSets>
  <DataSet>
    <Parameter id="1"/>
    <Parameter Description="My Description"/>
    <Parameter value="3.14"/>
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet>
    <Parameter id="2"/>
    <Parameter timeout="123"/>
  </DataSet>
</DataSets>
```

For validation I want to create a `XSD` schema. The most inner element `Parameter` can by **any** type with **any** name. There must be at least **one** of such element.

How to define the `XSD` scheme for this inner element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xs:any to specify any name and type. Your XML validates against the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="DataSets" type="dataSets"/>

    <xs:complexType name="dataSets">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="DataSet" type="dataSet" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="dataSet">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" processContents="lax" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: That solution allows Parameter to have any type, but to have any name as the question called for. To allow any name, you need to use a wildcard: replace `xs:element name="Parameter"` with xs:any.